# Magento currency switch doesn't show

Tags: magento-1.9

I've set up my magento store in 4 languages. For sales we want to put Pound in the currency check. This doesn't show in the header. Ill put the code here for all the files I adjusted:

page.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">

            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

            <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

            <action method="addJs"><script>magentothem/ma.jq.slide.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs" ><script>magentothem/jquery-ui.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>magentothem/ma.bxslider.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>bootstrap/bootstrap.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>magentothem/ma.mobilemenu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>magentothem/backtotop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>magentothem/ma.lettering.js</script></action>
                        <action method="addJs" ifconfig="banner7/banner7_config/enabled"><script>magentothem/ma.flexslider.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs" ifconfig="banner7/banner7_config/enabled"><script>magentothem/ma.nivo.js</script></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap-theme.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css</stylesheet></action>

           <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 9</if></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>magentothem/html5shiv.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 9</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>magentothem/respond.min.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 9</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
            <label>Page Top</label>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="ma_banner" as="ma_banner" translate="label" />
        <block type="core/text_list" name="home_banner_static" as="home_banner_static" translate="label" />
        <block type="core/text_list" name="banner_left" as="banner_left" translate="label" />
        <block type="core/text_list" name="banner_right" as="banner_right" translate="label" />
        <block type="core/text_list" name="brand_slider" as="brand_slider" translate="label" />

        <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
            <label>Left Column</label>

        </block>

        <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
        <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
            <label>Right Column</label>
        </block>

        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
            <label>Page Bottom</label>
            <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
        </block>
    </block>

    <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
</default>

<print translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages (Print Version)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Page -->
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/print.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>

    </block>
</print>

 <!-- Custom page layout handles -->
<page_empty translate="label">
    <label>All Empty Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/empty.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_empty>

<page_one_column translate="label">
    <label>All One-Column Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_one_column>

<page_two_columns_left translate="label">
    <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Left Column)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_left>

<page_two_columns_right translate="label">
    <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Right Column)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_right>

<page_three_columns translate="label">
    <label>All Three-Column Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</page_three_columns>
```

header.phtml file:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top-link">
             <div class="container-inner">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currency.phtml

[image: currency.phtml]

what am I doing wrong? It looks like it's not showing or finding the wright file or code. I think something is going wrong in the base information and files.

Comment: Add you total `page.xml` in the question!

Comment: Do you have added currency more than one?

Comment: @AsishHira add it.

Comment: @PrashantValanda how do you mean that?

Comment: Try to add `<?php echo $this->getCurrencyCount() ?>` on the top of `Currency.phtml` page. and see the count result.. It must have to be **0**. That means you did not set multiple currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have selected currency more than one from

**System > Configuration > General > Currency Setup > Currency Options > Allowed Currencies**

[image]

Also added rate from

**System > Manage Currency > Rates**

[image]

You will see currency switcher

[image]

Comment: thats it, forgot to fill in the second price convertion.